# How would one serialize nested collections when using a custom ISerializationSurrogate?

Tags: .net, serialization, netdatacontractserializer

I'm attempting to use a generic serialization surrogate to control the naming of fields that are serialized through use of the NetDataContractSerializer. The concept is working well so far except for that I'm running into a problem any time I encounter a field that holds a reference to a collection within the GetObjectData method in that calling AddValue and feeding it my collection type seems to result in no items in the collection being serialized. Is there something special I need to do for collections such as arrays or lists?

I've added a copy of my complete code with an example below in hopes that somebody may be able to point me in the right direction.

```
static void Main()
{
    var obj = new Club(
        "Fight Club", 
        Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(i => new Member() { Age = i, Name = i.ToString() }));

    var streamingContext = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.Clone);
    //var serializer = new NetDataContractSerializer(streamingContext);
    var serializer = new NetDataContractSerializer(streamingContext, int.MaxValue, false, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full, new MySurrogateSelector(streamingContext));
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);

    Console.WriteLine("Before serializing: \n{0}\n", obj);

    ms.Position = 0;
    var xml = XElement.Load(ms);
    Console.WriteLine("Serialized object: \n\n{0}\n", xml);

    ms.Position = 0;
    var deserializedObj = serializer.Deserialize(ms);

    Console.WriteLine("After deserializing: \n{0}\n", deserializedObj);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public class MySurrogateSelector : ISurrogateSelector
{
    private ISerializationSurrogate _surrogate = new BackingFieldSerializationSurrogate();

    public MySurrogateSelector(StreamingContext streamingContext)
    {
    }

    public void ChainSelector(ISurrogateSelector selector)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ISurrogateSelector GetNextSelector()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ISerializationSurrogate GetSurrogate(System.Type type, StreamingContext context, out ISurrogateSelector selector)
    {
        selector = null;
        return _surrogate;
    }
}


public class BackingFieldSerializationSurrogate : ISerializationSurrogate
{
    private static Regex _backingFieldRegex = new Regex("<(.*)>k__BackingField", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public void GetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.SetType(obj.GetType());
        var fields = obj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            string propertyName;
            info.AddValue(
                TryGetPropertyNameFromBackingField(field.Name, out propertyName) ? GenerateCustomBackingFieldName(propertyName) :
                field.Name,
                field.GetValue(obj),
                field.FieldType);
        }
    }

    public object SetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
    {
        var fields = obj.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            string propertyName;
            field.SetValue(
                obj,
                info.GetValue(
                TryGetPropertyNameFromBackingField(field.Name, out propertyName) ? GenerateCustomBackingFieldName(propertyName) :
                field.Name,
                field.FieldType));
        }

        return obj;
    }

    private static bool TryGetPropertyNameFromBackingField(string fieldName, out string propertyName)
    {
        var match = _backingFieldRegex.Match(fieldName);
        if (match.Groups.Count == 1)
        {
            propertyName = null;
            return false;
        }

        propertyName = match.Groups[1].Value;
        return true;
    }

    private static string GenerateCustomBackingFieldName(string propertyName)
    {
        return "_" + propertyName + "_k__BackingField";
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Member
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Member {0}, Age: {1}", Name, Age);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Club
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Member> Members { get; private set; }

    public Club(string name, IEnumerable<Member> members)
    {
        Name = name;
        //Members = new List<Member>(members);
        Members = members.ToArray();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (Members == null)
        {
            return Name;
        }

        return Name + ", Total members: " + Members.Count + "\n\t" +  string.Join("\n\t", Members);
    }
}
```

If anyone is curious the reason that I'm trying this technique is to get around an issue which causes internally handled XmlException of which have me concerned about performance implications.

```
System.Xml.XmlException occurred
  HResult=-2146232000
  Message=Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C.
  Source=System.Xml
  LineNumber=0
  LinePosition=1
  StackTrace:
       at System.Xml.XmlConvert.VerifyNCName(String name, ExceptionType exceptionType)
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I didn't give anybody else much of a chance to respond but I found out what seems to have been the underlying problem. After looking at the base SurrogateSelector class I realized that perhaps I was not returning the right kind of surrogate for a collection and that led me down a few paths until I eventually just tried detecting arrays and returning null from GetSurrogate in those cases. And like magic everything seemed to begin working as expected.

```
public ISerializationSurrogate GetSurrogate(Type type, StreamingContext context, out ISurrogateSelector selector)
{
    if (type.IsArray)
    {
        selector = null;
        return null;
    }

    selector = null;
    return _surrogate;
}
```

At first I was a bit surprised that this also seemed to correct other types of generic collections like List that I was also having issues with but essentially it appears that these collections are still broken down into arrays and direct object references so perhaps arrays are the only special case I was missing. I hope this may help somebody else who may come across similar issues dealing with the complexity of using the serialization surrogate classes.